# How does DataGridVIewRow count cells? ArgumentOutOfRangeException occured

Tags: c#

I'm having error of ArgumentOutOfRangeException. The reason is Cells.Count result is 15 whereas the only row I have is 5.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rw.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        if (rw.Cells[i].Value != null || rw.Cells[i].Value != DBNull.Value || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.Cells[i].Value.ToString()))
        {
            commcon.Open();

            //check if there is outstanding balances and with equal total with the collection partner unless partial or advance payment or for checking
            int obaccountid = 0;
            double obtotal = 0;

            int billno = 0;
            int accountid = 0;
            string accountno = "";
            string accountname = "";
            double total = 0;
            int cellnumber = 0;
            DateTime colldate;

            //setting value
            accountid = getAccountID(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            billno = getBillno(accountid);
            accountno = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            accountname = getProperAccountName(getAccountID(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()));
            total = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
            cellnumber = (int)Convert.ToInt64(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[14].Value);
            colldate = (DateTime)Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);

            //getting data from OB database
            //additional validation if the transaction month is same with the collection month and year
            using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 1 total, accountid FROM [bicos-ob].dbo.[Outstanding Bills] where accountid="
                + accountid + " and MONTH([billing date]) = MONTH('" + colldate + "') and YEAR([billing date]) = YEAR('" + colldate + "')  order by id desc", commcon))
            {
                DataTable t = new DataTable();
                a.Fill(t);
                if (t != null && t.Rows.Count > 0)  
                {
                    obtotal = Convert.ToDouble(t.Rows[0][0]);
                    obaccountid = Convert.ToInt32(t.Rows[1][0]);

                    //execution if total of outstanding bill and collection is equal
                    if (obtotal == total && obaccountid == accountid)
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[save__collection_RDPayments]", commcon);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billno", billno);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountid", accountid);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountno", accountno); //with Account Number Validation already. Format is already there.
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountname", accountname);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@or", ORNumber);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@collectiondate", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paymenttype", paymenttype);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkno", checkno);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@overpayment", 0);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partialpayment", 0);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", getUserID(user));
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RefNo", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString());
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        //format: accountno, accountid, accountname
                        appendFiles("Posted payment of: " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + " " + getAccountID(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()) + " " +
                            getProperAccountName(getAccountID(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString())));

                        string log = "Posted";
                        SqlCommand cmdlog = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO CodeAventus_ePostingPortal.dbo.[audit_cr_log] (collectiondate, accountno, accountname, remarks, transactiondate, cellphonenumber) " +
                            "VALUES(@collectiondate, @accountno, @accountname, @remarks, @transactiondate, @cellphonenumber)", commcon);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@collectiondate", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accoutno", accountno);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountname", accountname);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", log);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transactiondate", System.DateTime.Now);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cellphonenumber", cellnumber);

                        commcon.Close();
                    }
                    //overpayment
                    else if (obtotal < total && obaccountid == accountid)
                    {
                        string log = "Overpayment";
                        SqlCommand cmdlog = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO CodeAventus_ePostingPortal.dbo.[audit_cr_log] (collectiondate, accountno, accountname, remarks, transactiondate, cellphonenumber) " +
                            "VALUES(@collectiondate, @accountno, @accountname, @remarks, @transactiondate, @cellphonenumber)", commcon);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@collectiondate", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountno", accountno);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountname", accountname);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", log);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transactiondate", System.DateTime.Now);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cellphonenumber", cellnumber);
                        cmdlog.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        commcon.Close();
                    }
                    //partial
                    else if (obtotal > total && obaccountid == accountid)
                    {
                        string log = "Paid amount is less than posted bill.";
                        SqlCommand cmdlog = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO CodeAventus_ePostingPortal.dbo.[audit_cr_log] (collectiondate, accountno, accountname, remarks, transactiondate, cellphonenumber) " +
                            "VALUES(@collectiondate, @accountno, @accountname, @remarks, @transactiondate, @cellphonenumber)", commcon);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@collectiondate", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountno", accountno);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountname", accountname);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", log);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transactiondate", System.DateTime.Now);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cellphonenumber", cellnumber);
                        cmdlog.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        commcon.Close();
                    }
                    else if (obaccountid != accountid)
                    {
                        string log = "Wrong Account Number.";
                        SqlCommand cmdlog = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO CodeAventus_ePostingPortal.dbo.[audit_cr_log] (collectiondate, accountno, accountname, remarks, transactiondate, cellphonenumber) " +
                            "VALUES(@collectiondate, @accountno, @accountname, @remarks, @transactiondate, @cellphonenumber)", commcon);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@collectiondate", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountno", accountno);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountname", accountname);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", log);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transactiondate", System.DateTime.Now);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cellphonenumber", cellnumber);
                        cmdlog.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        commcon.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string log = "unknown";
                        SqlCommand cmdlog = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO CodeAventus_ePostingPortal.dbo.[audit_cr_log] (collectiondate, accountno, accountname, remarks, transactiondate, cellphonenumber) " +
                            "VALUES(@collectiondate, @accountno, @accountname, @remarks, @transactiondate, @cellphonenumber)", commcon);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@collectiondate", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountno", accountno);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountname", accountname);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", log);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transactiondate", System.DateTime.Now);
                        cmdlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cellphonenumber", cellnumber);
                        cmdlog.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        commcon.Close();
                    }
                }
                //datatable is null
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No data retrieved!", "MESSAGE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    commcon.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error. Check the column header", "MESSAGE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            commcon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the Cells.Count is 15.
Program stops at value of i = 5; while Cells.Count is 15.

Updated my post. Added more code. I'm hoping for more suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: What are you doing in `//my code` exactly?

Comment: @Logarr validation and insertion of data to DB.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the debugger to verify that your count is not actually 15 at the time of evaluation in in this loop? This is what the Locals window is for.

Comment: If you study how to use the DB provider objects, you do not need to iterate rows or columns to insert,, update or delete from the database.

Comment: @Logarr Yes. Cells.Count is actually 15. and program stops at value of i=5.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp Will check it out.

Comment: @letsjigsaw Can we please see what is your code inside the `for` loop block? You potentially have a condition for a return of break. Otherwise `i` will always run to the `count`.

Comment: `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is a very common exception to occur if you apply `i` to an list that is less length or you forgot to `i - 1`.

Comment: What C# technology are you using? Can I get more context of what you're trying to do.

Comment: on which line exactly does the exception occur? The debugger should help examine all variables in that line..

Comment: Where is `dataGridView1` declared? Is the code shown in a xaml page code behind? If so please show the xaml for the data grid. Perhaps you have left it to auto-populate column headers based upon data source binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there's your problem...

Your loop is iterating over your `Cells` count, but you're using the `i` index to select from your `Rows` collection. You have (at least) 15 cells on your rows as indicated by the following hardcoded index of `14`:

```
cellnumber = (int)Convert.ToInt64(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[14].Value);
```

So you're right that you don't have 15 rows, but that's not the number you're looping with. It looks like you've got a mess of what you're trying to accomplish in this loop. In the beginning you're checking if the current cell is null or empty, which is good, but then inside the loop you're trying to access specific cells. You haven't checked those cells for null/empty.

Are you only intending to check the header row or something? Your error message would lead me to believe so. If so then I'd take a whole different approach to your `foreach` loop.